# Why does gcc99 point at meaningless error while standard gcc does not?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I'm learning ALSA programming by [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735) and I've tried to compile the following example:

```
/*

This example opens the default PCM device, sets
some parameters, and then displays the value
of most of the hardware parameters. It does not
perform any sound playback or recording.

*/

/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

/* All of the ALSA library API is defined
 * in this header */
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main() {
  int rc;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val, val2;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;

  /* Open PCM device for playback. */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,
                              SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
  val = 44100;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle,
                                 params, &val, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Display information about the PCM interface */

  printf("PCM handle name = '%s'\n",
         snd_pcm_name(handle));

  printf("PCM state = %s\n",
         snd_pcm_state_name(snd_pcm_state(handle)));

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_access(params,
                          (snd_pcm_access_t *) &val);
  printf("access type = %s\n",
         snd_pcm_access_name((snd_pcm_access_t)val));

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_format(params, (snd_pcm_format_t *) &val);
  printf("format = '%s' (%s)\n",
    snd_pcm_format_name((snd_pcm_format_t)val),
    snd_pcm_format_description(
                             (snd_pcm_format_t)val));

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_subformat(params,
                        (snd_pcm_subformat_t *)&val);
  printf("subformat = '%s' (%s)\n",
    snd_pcm_subformat_name((snd_pcm_subformat_t)val),
  snd_pcm_subformat_description(
                        (snd_pcm_subformat_t)val));

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &val);
  printf("channels = %d\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &val, &dir);
  printf("rate = %d bps\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params,
                                    &val, &dir);
  printf("period time = %d us\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params,
                                    &frames, &dir);
  printf("period size = %d frames\n", (int)frames);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_time(params,
                                    &val, &dir);
  printf("buffer time = %d us\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(params,
                         (snd_pcm_uframes_t *) &val);
  printf("buffer size = %d frames\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods(params, &val, &dir);
  printf("periods per buffer = %d frames\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_numden(params,
                                &val, &val2);
  printf("exact rate = %d/%d bps\n", val, val2);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_sbits(params);
  printf("significant bits = %d\n", val);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_tick_time(params,
                                  &val, &dir);
  printf("tick time = %d us\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_is_batch(params);
  printf("is batch = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_is_block_transfer(params);
  printf("is block transfer = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_is_double(params);
  printf("is double = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_is_half_duplex(params);
  printf("is half duplex = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_is_joint_duplex(params);
  printf("is joint duplex = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_can_overrange(params);
  printf("can overrange = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_can_mmap_sample_resolution(params);
  printf("can mmap = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_can_pause(params);
  printf("can pause = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_can_resume(params);
  printf("can resume = %d\n", val);

  val = snd_pcm_hw_params_can_sync_start(params);
  printf("can sync start = %d\n", val);

  snd_pcm_close(handle);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that if I compile it with

> gcc test.c -std=c99 -lasound

I get the following:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:36:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘alloca’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
   ^
```

But this warning does not appear if I don't use

> -std=c99

1. Why do I even get this warning?
2. Why there is no such problem with the standard C version?

Comment: I'd guess from the error message that `snd_pcn_hw_params_alloca` is actually a `#define` macro for something involving `alloca`, which is a function that is not part of Standard C.   `-std=c99` is the standard version; if you give no flags then you get GNU extensions which includes `alloca`.

Comment: To fix this, look for a different function/macro for allocating or initializing `params` that does not mention `alloca`

Comment: That is not a meaningless error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`man alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) you should add `alloca.h` to your includes when you are using `alloca()`:

```
 #include <alloca.h>
```

This is not usual function, because it should directly modify stack of the function from which it is called. It is handled specially in the compiler, for example in gcc (as described [in the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html))

> *Notes on the GNU version*
>
> ```
>   Normally, gcc(1) translates calls to alloca() with inlined code.
>    This is not done when either the -ansi, -std=c89, -std=c99, or the
>    -std=c11 option is given and the header <alloca.h> is not included.
>    Otherwise, (without an -ansi or -std=c* option) the glibc version of
>    <stdlib.h> includes <alloca.h> and that contains the lines...
> ```

You are using `alloca` because `snd_pcm_info_alloca` is defined as macro with `alloca` (thank you, Matt McNabb)

```
#define snd_pcm_info_alloca(ptr) do { assert(ptr); *ptr = (snd_pcm_info_t *) alloca(snd_pcm_info_sizeof()); memset(*ptr, 0, snd_pcm_info_sizeof()); } while (0)
```

Incomplete [ALSA doc about `snd_pcm_info_alloca`](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html) says

> snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(ptr)
>     allocate an invalid snd_pcm_hw_params_t using standard alloca

but the alloca is not standard; when you use it you should include `alloca.h`

I think that example in http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735?page=0,1 is incorrect; and good examples like http://webpages.lss.supelec.fr/perso/kowalski/?download=playback.c or https://gitorious.org/alsa/alsa-tools/source/f768eb0ff4124ac7e795cee09acb797fd01b63f1:ac3dec/output.c have `#include <alloca.h>`.

This `snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca` macro should be used with caution, incorrect usage may lead to use after free errors: http://mailman.alsa-project.org/pipermail/alsa-devel/2008-March/006700.html

Comment: And it's a bug in alsa-lib, they should fix their headers.